# How to Change Width of Elements in a Visio Shape

Tags: microsoft-visio

I am trying to visualize my database structure using Visio 2016 and Crow's Foot Notation. Viso provides an `Entity` shape as shown below. I want to change the dimensions of the shape elements so that the contents are presented nicely. In this case, the data type column is too narrow to show the content properly, so I'd like to make it a bit wider. Changing the overall width of the shape only changes the attribute name column, but the data type column width remains constant. I can un-group the elements and then define their properties, but that breaks their link to the container and the behavior of the shape. How can I change it without breaking the container?

[image: Entity]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you select the shape you'll see two yellow control handles.  The right-hand one controls the width of the container and the bottom one the width of the Type column.

[image]

Comment: Wow - why didn't I see that?  Thank you!