# Remove hidden margin on Visio 2019 Entity Relationship Diagram

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2019

Using Visio 2019, I'm trying to do the following:

1. File -> New -> Crow's Foot Database Notation template
2. Drag an "Entity" shape type onto the page
3. Name an attribute something long

As you can see from the screenshot below, the name wraps around to the next line, despite there being more than enough space.

[image]

Simply put, I want that attribute name to fill the space horizontally so that it doesn't have to wrap around, but I can't figure out how.

Here's what I've tried, in what I think is order of obviousness:

- Resizing to have more horizontal space - doesn't work
  [image]
- Left-aligning text - doesn't work
  [image]
- Dragging a yellow dot (as per [How to Change Width of Elements in a Visio Shape](https://superuser.com/questions/1026186/how-to-change-width-of-elements-in-a-visio-shape)) - doesn't work, because I'm using an "Entity" and not an "Entity with Attributes", there is only one yellow dot, which controls the width. That's what I used to make the entity wider in the first bullet point, it doesn't help the weird margin though.
  [image]

The only thing I've found that comes close to what I want is to right-click the Entity and click "Ungroup". This actually shows me the weird margin as a solid line. Unfortunately, it's not selectable at all, so I can't figure out how to move it or delete it - but it does show that something is there, which is interesting.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out just a few minutes after posting it.

The first thing I tried was to click on one of the attributes, click the popout menu for Paragraph, then switch to Text Block. That's when I noticed that the "Right" margin is 80pt. I tried to change it to 0, but after you hit OK, nothing changes. When you go back to that dialog box, it sets itself back to 80.

[image]

Inspired by this answer that I saw while Googling my question, https://superuser.com/a/1288661/456678, I wondered if the padding had some kind of "GUARD" function on it, which it turns out it does! To fix it, do the following:

1. Enable the Developer tab in Visio: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/show-the-developer-tab-e1192344-5e56-4d45-931b-e5fd9bea2d45
2. Select the attribute, go to the Developer tab, and click on "Show ShapeSheet"
3. Scroll down to "Text Box Format", and check out the long formula in "RightMargin": `=GUARD(IF(LISTSHEETREF()!User.SHOWTYPE,60 pt,80 pt))`. For my purposes, I simply changed this to `=0`, but it would also work to change the numbers in the formula, or to write your own formula.

**Before:**
[image]

**After:**
[image]